# How to refresh View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a sport app and to keep it very simple there are three view controllers.

- Main view controller
- Event view controller
- Player view controller

In the *event controller* is a list of events that happen during a match (pass, kick, tackle etc) when the user clicks the event they are then taken to the view controller with a list of players. The user selects a player and then that information (ID, event and player name) are set to an external database, and the user is taken back to the event view controller. Under each event is a label showing how many times that button has been pressed. This number goes up each time it's pressed. But I don't want it to go up un till the player as also been selected incase it was an error.

Anyway heres my code for the button in the player view controller.

```
-(IBAction)prop1Button:(id)sender{
_textField3.text = @"15";
[self postMessage: self.textField2.text withName:self.textField3.text];
_textField2.text = nil;
_textField3.text = nil;
dropGoalCounter ++;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This works fine, and updates the number but only when the user goes back to the main view controller and then into the event view controller.

How do I get it to refresh?

Thanks

Comment: How are you checking that the number is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the text property for the label after you increment the value. You may want to make sure the save was successful before setting it though, in case it doesn't actual save - so you don't show the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code in viewDidLoad that sets the value of the label? If so you might need code in viewWillAppear to update the value.

Comment: I do have the code in the viewDidLoad section. What do I need to do in viewWillAppear?

Comment: If you pop back to a view viewWillAppear will be called instead of viewDidLoad.  Sometimes I create a function with startup code and call it in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear so that it will get called when you first see a view and when you pop back to it.